# How to deal with variable pay as a developer?

Tags: salary, contracts, france

I am going to sign a new contract in a start-up. As we discussed the pay, they warned me a part of the pay was variable. They intend to pay it all the time and partly or totally remove it in case of professional fault, to paraphrase their wording. They implemented this after bad experience with previous programmer who came only when he wanted to and they had no possiblity to fire, and made it very clear they did not intend to use it as "motivation" or objective-based tool.

This seemed very odd to me. I am not a lawyer, but I tried to search if what they were planning to do could make it into the contract, but I found no similar case. From what I understood though, it seems that in my country (France), variable pay can only be made by objectives contract and can be claimed fully by the employee if the employer failed to provide an objective proof they were not fulfilled (this is mostly used for commercial commissions).

I want to make things as clear as possible and even warned them about the consequence of lack of objectives, but they simply assured me they would make it clear in the contract. They sounded like they didn't want to bother right now.

Should I pressure for more details now, while i'm quitting my job, or when the moment comes to sign my new contract ?

**EDIT: What happened next**

I see this topic is getting more answers so I'm giving a bit of feedback of how I am coping with the situation.

I asked them for more precision by e-mail before I sign the promise, knowing that whatever they answered had legal value and had high chances to be what would be in the contract. They wrote me back the objectives would be both qualitative (respect of processes, implication, motivation) and objective-based (features etc.), so their answer *was* different than what they originally stated.

That does mean they have a lever of pressure there, however, being confident of my own performance, not being in need of any penny of the variable amount which is pure bonus compared to what I currently earn, and considering I also have advantages regarding work time, place, and job interest, I am fine with these conditions.

I can see most of you consider having a variable pay as a symbol of distrust or poor management ability or both because you consider this 10% as a potential malus (and I think it's a mistake by them to have it presented to me this way the first time), while truely it is potential bonus, that they are, according to them, giving away for doing average. Devs might not be sellers, but bounties can be motivating to anyone, and I can understand a manager wants to keep his devs motivated. Giving money reward has nothing inhuman :). In itself, the money isn't a problem, if I never gain it it's still "OK" the problem would be the lie, not the money.

This is my POV and I'm 99% sure there will be a huge flow of disagreement, but my answer is this: is it better I make my own experience if this model fits me, or that I trust people that don't know me saying it wouldn't ?

Note that I made my own judgement on the employer, he look friendly/honest/fine. This was a two sides interview, I am not jumping on the first opportunity blindly.

Comment: You should certainly not quit your current job until you have seen the new contract. That would be stupid.

Comment: So who gets to decide when you have committed "professional fault"? Is there an independent arbitration mechanism?  Do you get to appeal any decision?

Comment: @TonyK The employment promise has legal value of a job contract (i.e. i can get paid if they don't respect it) but it only says the amount of pay that is variable, not the terms. It may sound like a frail offer, but the start-up is already more appealing in terms of job interest (technologies used) and salary (even without the variable part) than my current job, so I'm not so sure it's stupid.

Comment: Just to repeat @TonyK's comment: don't quit until you find a new job and you have a signed contract in hand. (Unless you can and don't mind living on savings until you look for a job.)

Comment: @ArthurHavlicek It most defintely looks stupid. :)  I wouldn't sign this offer even for the most interesting job ever. You don't know anything about the startup other than what they showed you but you _do_ know they're already setting you up.

Comment: I would be backing away slowly from this one!

Comment: No way I would ever even remotely consider signing there or working there. And somehow I doubt that they have legally a leg to stand on in France, which would make it doubly stupid. @JaneS: I would be running away as fast as I can!

Comment: Haha, sounds like you're talking about my previous employers, in France as well :) As we say here: Courage, Fuyons! (Meaning, run away from these people)

Comment: @ArthurHavlicek your update makes me think that they felt your hesitation and changed their discourse. Remember their initial idea was a punishment in case of professional fault. This is what they're really thinking about, even if they changed the wording afterwards. By the way their criterias ("respect of rules, implication, motivation") are all subjective (who judges implication and motivation? What are the "rules"?) and have no solid foundation at all, and are in no way related to the quality of the work you'll provide.

Comment: @Jivan Even when speaking about objective criteria, or work quality (objectivity in this ?), the employer still have the final word, let's be honnest about it. I still prefer this version than something more vague. Face to face the manager also told me "the walls will tremble long before we touch your pay". The point is, they are proving criteria are at least not a taboo, and I probably will be able to defend myself if it happens they want to block the variable pay - and if I'm wrong on this, then I'll be able to search a new job while being employed. Sounds fair to me.

Comment: @ArthurHavlicek well if you wanna go that road, then go for it and, as you say, "make your own experience" ;) **Everybody** on this site will have warned you, though. It's just kind of sad because as I said, the problem is not with this pay-detail, but with the lack of culture that it shows, clearly they are non-technical persons who just happen to do business with software instead of potatoes, just because it's more opportunistic.

Comment: @Jivan, actually, it's more IT people doing business by accident. CEO is the founder of a well known open source software. They do lack HR experience, but I still want to try this out.

Comment: *They implemented this after bad experience with previous programmer who came only when he wanted to and they had no possiblity to fire,...* So? Why do the actions of a previous employee have to influence you? Their assertion that they *were not able to fire him* may very well point to errors THEY made, like bad contracts, insufficient knowledge or experience with these cases or their laws - so again, why would that have to influence you?

Comment: @JanDoggen I don't get your point. I mean, you are right, even I find it a poor reason for implementing such a system. But what matters is what I can do regarding their decision now, given they left me no negociation alternative (quoting the manager "everybody here, even I, have a variable part")

Comment: Arthur, I'm curious how this turned out. Did you take the job? Did you get screwed? Please let us know!

Comment: Took the job. It is fine now, I got my variable part without doing anything special, and I'm not doing any extra hour. I have a mixed feeling about the management though. We are seriously understaffed and I feel the overall pressure on mistakes that can delay relases or bug the software, although implicit, is real, but that may also be that I can't handle it as well as I used to. I'm having a bit tough personal life right now.

Comment: But everything else is as great as I expected it to be. Good human relationships. Interesting work. Pay is OK. Working hours are flexible and I'm never asked to do extra.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Any innovations or complications in how you get paid is a red flag. I would get clarification first, or more probably look elsewhere for a job.

It's putting you in the same category as a fruit picker who gets paid by how many baskets of apples he fills (even when it rains). It's all about incentive, and it leaves all the power in the hands of the employer. So be very careful.

In terms of being a developer under this scheme, it really looks to me like they want the convenience of having a consultant, without the consultants pay and control.

Comment: Sounds far worse than the fruit picker example. From the OPs description, he could pick plenty of baskets and still be told "no, you picked them wrong, we're not paying you". Sounds like a get-out clause to simply not pay staff unless the startup becomes a unicorn success.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, and all other comments. I started to pressure for more *written* details by mail. Note that I'm not really willing to look elsewhere right away because the job really look good for everything but that "detail".

Comment: How you are paid certainly seems like a big "detail".

Comment: Is the job good enough for you to work for free?

Comment: @Nelson that would be charity not work :P

Comment: If anyone says "Don't worry about it, we'll take good care of you." or "Leave it to us, we'll make sure you're well looked after." as they look you straight in the eye while giving you a firm handshake and a sincere smile.... run, and don't look back, just keep running.

Answer (score 13):

French guy here.

A few years ago, I've been in the exact same situation you describe, and I made the mistake of signing.

The problem you'll find if you sign is not necessarily that you won't get part of your pay sooner or later. That contingency would at least prove manageable in some way.

No, the real problem here is that by offering this proposal to you, they do nothing but prove a **serious and irretrievable lack of culture** about what is a software developer and how he works. They pretend to be a startup, but they do apply fundamentally "agency-like" reasonings. They even confessed not being capable of managing and motivating developers (the last one, in their terms, came to "do what he wanted and show only when he pleased").

Knowing nothing about software development, they want to have a trigger to better control you and better pressure you, if only unconsciously, so that you'll be tempted to shut your mouth if problems arise.

And if you don't, they'll cut your pay, knowing that it would be an enormous pain in the ass for you to go legal about it (long procedures, nothing to be gained in the end...).

Been there, done that. Run from this [toxic environment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8TyjdbdPmB8), and find a true "startup".

***-- Responding to your update***

Your update makes me think that they felt your hesitation and changed their discourse.

Remember **their initial idea was of a punishment** in case of professional fault. This is what they're really thinking about, even if they changed the wording afterwards. Otherwise, why would they have even mention this possibility in the first place?

Additionally, their criterias ("*respect of rules, implication, motivation*") are all subjective:

- Who judges implication and motivation?
- What are the "rules"?

Those criterias have no solid foundation at all, and are in no way related to the quality of the work you'll provide.

Lastly, you say:

> I made my own judgement on the employer, he look friendly/honest/fine

Remember that as a recruiter/boss/manager, it's *his job* to look friendly/honest/fine in order to keep people coming to work at his place. In no case it means that he really is. Makes me think of people who buy something because "the salesman was nice and appeared honest". Yeah, it's just his full-time job to appear nice and honest.

Comment: The full story of the predecessor was on a previous company. The manager was bossing someone who had big personal issues and took a long illness break (iirc someone close to him died). When he came back he seemed inept of taking back the responsibilities he previously had, but the company was just back from a big social plan, and there was big social pressure. The manager was told the guy was staying no matter what. But this is a side story, I didn't care about it really and still took full measure about what variable pay meant.

Comment: Okay, I think I must have overreacted then, because it sounded exactly like the beginning of one previous case I had to deal with, and it ended up like I described. But I understand it's different in your case!

Answer (score 8):

I'm not a lawyer and this is not legal advice.

Paying salaries is a cost of doing business. When an employee doesn't perform up to the expected levels, the business can let that person go but in most Western countries, it's not legal to not to pay the salary. The business can sue the employee or report the employee to the police if they so desire but they're (usually) obligated to pay the full salary. Based on the actions of an employee, a court may decide that some of it must be paid back but that needs a court decision.

I'd certainly not sign a contract like this (unless being *really* pressed for work but then I'd start looking again right away). This sort of wording looks like a setup to cut salaries based on arbitrary rules. Whatever they promise is not written down, only their ability to not to pay you.

Comment: Agreed, I would have to be out of work and insanely desperate to ever agree to a contract like this. As long as there is one real job available, avoid this "startup".

Comment: Not sure where the OP is, but here if you are employed as an independent contractor, you almost always are required to have professional indemnity insurance.  That covers the case where a developer causes significant financial damage to the employer by going through official channels, rather than docking pay arbitrarily.  If enough money has been lost to withhold money, then it should absolutely warrant going through a proper arbitration process.

Comment: @JaneS I was under the impression that the OP would be employed as a full-time employee, not as a contractor.

Comment: @xxbbcc Then I would _definitely_ recommend the OP run away as fast as possible.

Comment: A contract has to provide benefit to both sides. If there could be a case where the employee is not paid because of unsubstantiated 'non-performance', I don't see the benefit. As others have already said; run away! run away!

Answer (score 1):

> Should I pressure for more details now, while i'm quitting my job, or when the moment comes to sign my new contract ?

**Your strongest bargaining position is now**, before deciding to leave.

> They sounded like they didn't want to bother right now.

This does not seem like an employer who is going to carefully follow a procedure to determine if you are at fault; it's an option for dealing with cash shortages or securing political leverage, neither of which work in your favour. **Assume the actual salary is the amount advertised minus the 'performance penalty'**. Does it still look like a good deal?

Before you decide, consider also how they've handled problems in the past:

> They implemented this after bad experience with previous programmer who came only when he wanted to and they had no possiblity to fire

**Their approach is to ignore problems, not solve them**. They say they had a bad developer who took frequently took unauthorised leave. They didn't do anything about it. They will probably be recruiting other bad developers, and bad managers who avoid managing, and failing to either turn them into good developers/managers or to fire them. Their 'solution' is to threaten you and other hires with financial penalties. That won't make incompetent colleagues capable, but it might make people do stupid things to avoid penalties (like coming in when sick). So not only will you be stuck dealing with incompetent colleagues, your superiors might not be able to tell the difference between the good and the bad, and you might get penalised as well when things go bad. Or the dead weight of the bad staff and the culture of 'nobody else does a good job, why should I?' might destroy the business. Anybody who's any good is going to find it hard to change this culture because anyone who speaks up might be arbitrarily penalised. Is this somewhere you want to work?

On the other hand, if you are looking to leave your current job because you're a poor performer and your managers are starting to realise it, this might be worth the gamble.

Comment: You can't fire people in France.  A job in France is a job for life.  If they're hired as a temp, they still can't fire them.  Only let their contract expire.

Comment: @Jack: That's not true, you can fire people. However, there are legal hurdles, you need to have a good reason, and you will usually have to pay a severance package. It may be difficult, but it's not impossible.